# How to programmatically login on SharePoint Online and get web HTML?

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, web-crawler, csom

I am using C# and CSOM, and would like to achieve a goal for a SharePoint Online site with following steps:

1. acquire a `list_id` by a given list name (this step is very easy with CSOM)
2. use the `list_id` to access page: `https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List={list_id}` (the list setting page according to the list ID)
3. grab the whole page HTML content, then do some further GET/POST operations

My issue is: I am stuck on step 2 & 3, unable to login into the SharePoint Online site programmatically and hold the session context for a further successive GET/POST operations.

---

- actually I am already done this on multiple SharePoint OnPerm sites successfully, using `var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler{Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)})`
- then use this `HttpClient` to login into the OnPerm site, and hold the login context for further GET/POST requests

My intention to SharePoint Online is same as above, with a given `string site`, `string username` and `SecureString password`, to login the SharePoint Online site and do GET/POST programmatically.

---

Currently I am simply using `SharePointOnlineCredentials` for replacing `NetworkCredential` to get a `HttpClient` for login, but only get 401 and 502 errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the WebClient to get the page HTML in SharePoint. The following code for your reference.

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com";
            string userName = "xxx@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            string password = "xxx";
            string listName = "listname";

            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
            var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            ctx.Credentials = credentials;
            var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            ctx.Load(list);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                wc.Credentials = credentials;
                wc.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC)";
                var pageHtml = wc.DownloadString(siteUrl + "/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List={" + list.Id.ToString() + "}");
                Console.WriteLine(pageHtml);
            }          
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```