# Get SharePoint online user access token without registering as app

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, office365, sharepoint-online, office365api

I am looking at way to get user token with userid and password for sharepoint online via c#. I can register as app with clientid and client secret but I am not looking for it.

PnP has powershell commend Get-PnPAccessToken and just need same via C#.

Is there a way to get it for SharePoint online via c#?

Many thanks,

Comment: Is there any update ? Did the OfficeDevPnP.Core library work to get user access token ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the OfficeDevPnP.Core library can also get the access token, install with Nuget Console command:

Install-Package SharePointPnPCoreOnline -Version 3.28.2012

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace UserAccessToken
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com";
            string userName = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            string Password = "********";

            var accessToken = GetUserAuthToken(siteUrl,userName, Password);
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static string GetUserAuthToken(string siteUrl, string userPrincipal, string Pwd)
        {
            var authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
            var context = authManager.GetAzureADCredentialsContext(siteUrl, userPrincipal, Pwd);
            Console.WriteLine(context.GetAccessToken());
            return context.GetAccessToken();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Reference:

[How to get access token in SharePoint Online using CSOM and use in Postman or Google Rest client](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/get-access-token-in-sharepoint-online/)

Answer (score 0):

The simple method to access SharePoint Online resources is using .Net SDK([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee544361(v=office.15))). You could refer to the code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164585/13308381).

---

[ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)(Resource Owner Password Credentials) flow allows an application to sign in the user by directly handling their password. But it requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows. So it's not recommended.

**Note:** Make sure you have added the required delegated permissions for SharePoint Online.

```
result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new UserPasswordCredential(username, password));
```

For more information, see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-username-and-password).