# Bring up Sharepoint prompt in .NET5

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

We used to be able  to log into `SharePoint Online` using the `SharePointOnlineCredentials` class eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151040/how-to-programmatically-login-on-sharepoint-online-and-get-web-html).

This class is not available in .NET5 and I don't have the necessary Azure permissions to configure the application in Azure AD as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#using-modern-authentication-with-csom-for-net-standard)

I'd like a C# program bring up a prompt, so the user can log into Sharepoint manually.  Once the user has done this the program will do what it needs to do.  Is there some C# code that will bring up the Sharepoint online login prompt?

I've downloaded Pnp and CSOM.  This code contains the following errors.

The name 'GetSecureString' does not exist in the current context

No overload for method 'GetContext' takes 3 arguments

'Program.GetContext(Uri, string, SecureString)': not all code paths return a value
The name 'context' does not exist in the current context

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using PnP.Framework;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri site = new Uri("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA");
        string user = "joe.doe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
        SecureString password = GetSecureString($"Password for {user}");

        // Note: The PnP Sites Core AuthenticationManager class also supports this
        using (var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager())
        using (var context = authenticationManager.GetContext(site, user, password))
        {
            context.Load(context.Web, p => p.Title);
            await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Title: {context.Web.Title}");
        }
    }
    public ClientContext GetContext(Uri web, string userPrincipalName, 
SecureString userPassword)
    {
        context.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Get an access token using your preferred approach
            string accessToken = MyCodeToGetAnAccessToken(new Uri($" 
  {web.Scheme}://{web.DnsSafeHost}"), userPrincipalName, new 
   System.Net.NetworkCredential(string.Empty, userPassword).Password);
            // Insert the access token in the request
            e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = 
"Bearer " + accessToken;
        };
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard
Your question should be answered by the tutorial in the microsoft docs.
have you tried using the below function of the AuthenticationManager?
https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/d726fb8c024db8ae237eba156286ac2a34a4d94c/src/lib/PnP.Framework/AuthenticationManager.cs#L178

Comment: also just to be clear, the latest nugget package from the PnP community is the Pnp.framework.

Comment: I think I've got it using a combination of static main method and the longer method below.  Thank you.